# ArcGIS Pro error 999999 using spatial join on the SOLRIS 3.0 data/layer

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, buffer, spatial-join, error-999999

I am pretty new to GIS but am trying to use the spatial join tool with the SOLRIS 3.0 data and my own data consisting of polygons. I am getting back the error code mentioned above and am so new at all of this, I'm not sure where to start. The SOLRIS dataset is I believe a raster dataset with land cover types denoted as a value (i.e., 90 being forested, 91 being coniferous forest, etc.,). I want these to be different feature classes and tried converting them to polygons but I'm afraid that's where my issue lies.

I think what I'm doing is relatively simple overall, I just need help moving past the raster dataset issue and the error code related to the spatial join. I am trying to determine how many forested areas (>15ha), urban areas and waterbodies lie within a 4km buffer of each polygon and what the distance is to the closest one of each category. As well as the percentage of area these landcover types cover and the distance from each of my polygons to the nearest patch of each landcover type. My plan was to use a combination of buffer and spatial join analysis but I'm at a roadblock.

https://geohub.lio.gov.on.ca/documents/0279f65b82314121b5b5ec93d76bc6ba/about
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/999001-999999/tool-errors-and-warnings-999998-999999-999999.htm

Comment: There is a file geodatabase (vector) (plus tif image) here with classifications (1.7GB of data unzipped) https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0279f65b82314121b5b5ec93d76bc6ba

Comment: This is the data I have but my problem is when I go to do the spatial join it only lets me select the raster dataset or the land cover changes and corrections feature classes. I can't access the actual classifications.